# Excel Text Split with one condition using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've been able to split text in VBA to separate a series of numbers from one cell into 4 different cells. What I've been using works but I can't find a way to set a condition to ignore splitting it if the source cell isn't in a certain format.

When it's a series of numbers separated by a period, split the text. This already works. However, when it's just a number with no periods, I want it to ignore splitting it.

So for example,

5.10.4.3456 in C2 get split into 4 different cells starting on C14 = 5, C15=10, C16=4, C17=3456 and this works with no issue. However, when the number doens't have periods separating it (highlighted text in attachment), is there a way to ignore the split of the remaining cells in that column? The dataset will continue to grow every time we export a new set so the range will grow weekly.

I select an entire column using Range and then split it but there are more random single numbers that should be ignored (highlighted in attachment).

```
Range("C2:C12085").Select

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Selection
rng.TextToColumns _
    Destination:=rng(1, 1).Offset(, 14), _
    TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    SemiColon:=False, _
    Comma:=False, _
    Other:=True, _
    Space:=False, _
    OtherChar:="."
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use `=VALUE(TEXTSPLIT(RC[-1],"."))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text-to-columns split function requires a contiguous range of cells without gaps. But you can remove the unwanted cells from the destination range after splitting.

```vb
    Dim rng As Range, lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("C2:C" & lastRow)
    rng.TextToColumns _
        Destination:=rng(1, 1).Offset(, 14), _
        TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        SemiColon:=False, _
        Comma:=False, _
        Other:=True, _
        Space:=False, _
        OtherChar:="."
        
    Dim arrs, arrd, i
    Dim rngD As Range
    arrs = rng.Value
    ' assuming text-to-column result in Q to T
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngD = Cells(2, "Q").Resize(lastRow - 1, 4)
    arrd = rngD.Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrs)
        If arrs(i, 1) = arrd(i, 1) Then arrd(i, 1) = ""
    Next
    rngD.Value = arrd
End Sub
```

I have tested the code with your sample data. There isn't any extra number in the next column.

[image]

---

Screenshot from OP user. Column P may contain data. The issue is fixed in the updated code.

[image]

Comment: What I forgot to mention is that the dataset continues to grow every time we export a new set. The range will continue to change so that's why I was looking for a way to tell it to ignore spitting numbers in that column that don't have periods I've updated the original post to include the changing range

Comment: @Achilles I have updated the code which can handle increased datasete.

Comment: I tried it and it's still splitting the numbers that don't have periods (highlighted numbers in attachment) and it has created a long string of 1's in each cell of the adjacent column.

Comment: Please upload a screenshot to show " long string of 1's in each cell  of the adjacent column". It is helpful to understand your case.

Comment: please see above screenshot

Comment: I have tested the code successfully. Please review updated post. More context will help troubleshoot.

Comment: There is various data in columns D through P. That's gotta be what is causing what I'm seeing. I tried a clean sheet with the above data from column C and the output was correct without additional values in adjacent columns.

Comment: The code does not modify columns D:P. Check if column D has a formula returning `1`. Updated code precisely locates destination range.

Comment: "Assuming text-to-column result in Q to T" What did you mean by this part? I have been able  to duplicate the issue. I have dataset similar to what's listed just longer in rows. I have data such as 2.5.2.1200 and I have it extended to row 4973 and then I have 0 through 817 which ends on row 5791. If  I put any word such as "TEST" in cell P1, the issue occurs. With P1 being empty (which wouldn't be the case in real time), I have no issue at all. If P1 has text, the issue occurs every time.

Comment: The latest update worked! Even with the P1 being filled. The precise destination range was the issue and likely my fault for not initially listing that the range headers were not empty in my original post. Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

TextToColumns method needs a Range as the destination, and the Offset method doesn't return a Range.

Try this :
Sub SplitTextToColumns()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("C2:C12085")

```
rng.TextToColumns _
    Destination:=rng.Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, 14), _
    TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, _
    DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    SemiColon:=False, _
    Comma:=False, _
    Other:=True, _
    OtherChar:="."
```

End Sub

Comment: What I forgot to mention is that the dataset continues to grow every time we export a new set. The range will continue to change so that's why I was looking for a way to tell it to ignore spitting numbers in that column that don't have periods I've updated the original post to include the changing range